# Qt signals reach UI thread with noticeable delay

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt

I have a worker thread in my application, which occasionally recieves information that should be quickly displayed in QML UI. When I have such portion of information, I emit signal, which is received by object that lives on UI thread.

I want this process to be very responsive, so that changes are displayed in QML UI as quickly as possible (this matters because worker thread handles external controller, and I want the shortest "critical path" between user interaction with controller and UI change).

However I discovered, that the time difference between `emit signal()` and slot called in UI thread is always 20-40 milliseconds. Why so?

What can I do to speed up this? I tried calling `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` in worker thread after signal is emitted, but this barely changes anything.

Some thoughts:

- Can I call `processEvents` but for UI thread somehow?
- Use event with high priority instead of signal. Will it help?

OS: Win8.1, Qt 5.5

Comment: QCoreApplication::processEvents is for UI thread's event loop. Post more code about signal connection,  slot handler,  UI run loop .

Comment: Given that QML refreshes at the screen's refresh rate, you'll have a 16.6ms delay at 60Hz refresh rate *anyway*. A 20ms delay is normal, and a 40ms delay isn't wrong either. Your user can't tell anyway, so what's the problem. What are you trying to do? BTW, `processEvents` is almost never needed any properly written code. You definitely *don't* need it.

Answer (score 0):

When you emit a signal from a worker thread to the UI thread, it is put into the UI event queue, and delivered when the event queue is pumped and reaches that message. If your worker thread is a higher priority than your UI thread, then the UI thread will have to wait until the worker thread blocks. If the worker thread is the same priority it will complete it's time quanta, which may be 20ms. You can make your signal connect Direct rather than Queued, and then you will need to take care of thread safety yourself.

Comment: "UI thread will have to wait until the worker thread blocks" - where this information is from ? Threads execute in parallel

Comment: If your worker thread is a higher priority than your UI thread, then the UI thread will have to wait until the worker thread blocks.

Comment: @Alexey Andronov: " Threads execute in parallel”. Not on a single core system, and even on multicore the signal/slot message passing requires synchronization.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Even on single core there's multiple processes and threads are being executed via context swithing isn't it? What kind of syncronization? Signal is pushed into receiver's eventQueue asyncroniously - where's there any syncronization? : - )

Comment: Yes, context switching. In my book that's one process on the core at a time :). And for one thread to read what the other has written the signal) memory need to be synchronized at some point.

Comment: "If your worker thread is a higher priority than your UI thread, then the UI thread will have to wait until the worker thread blocks." Only on a single core system, or on a multi-core system with all cores busy with higher priority work.